# Why is my ListView begins from the bottom to top?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, listview

I have a listview of products whos adding one by one to an ArrayList from the DataBase.
The order of adding and the listview are equals (so that's ok).

**My problem is that the products are shows from the middle of the page
(i have to scroll down a lot to see them).**
[listview display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeZHK.jpg)
My XML :

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listviewmanager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="457dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:clickable="false"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="474dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </ScrollView>
</ListView>
```

thank you.

Comment: Why do you have a scrollview and linearlayout within your listview?

Comment: Because I had trouble with the scrolling so I added this. You have a better option to do it? I'd like to hear it :)

Comment: Please share your entire XML code. I also believe the first 2 items are empty as you can see the dividers on the screenshots but no data.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line in your `ListView`

```
android:layout_height="457dp"
```

with this line

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

With `match_parent` you fill the whole screen with your `ListView` not only `457dp`.

Comment: @D123 Remove the Scroll View and your LinearLayout from your Listview. (And set the height still on match_parent)